# How to link android app to a database server?

Tags: android, mysql, database, github, database-connection

We're trying to run this github project as a reference for our own project:
https://github.com/gaodayue/RESTaurant_android

It executed after a lot of effort but we can't seem to get past the login page which is shown in figure below. It just says "Unable to login, please try again." and doesn't get past that point. I imagine we need to setup a database server as given in the link below and link it to the app. https://github.com/gaodayue/RESTaurant_backend

We don't have much knowledge regarding database servers so how can we get past the login page and access the app? I've already setup all the softwares as said in the backend link, now what would be the next step. Serious help required.

Comment: Specifically for the login, take a look at the [`LoginActivity.java`](https://github.com/gaodayue/RESTaurant_android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/uliamar/restaurant/app/controller/LoginActivity.java) for the Android client to see how login is handled. **However**, my guess is that you need some kind of database for this project to work as intended.

Comment: Yes, we do need a database for our app. The backend database for the project is given in this link https://github.com/gaodayue/RESTaurant_backend  But how do we link this to the android project?

Comment: Great. So what exactly is your question? Where exactly are you having trouble?

Comment: @LarsKristensen We've completed the deployment part of the app as said in this site: https://github.com/gaodayue/RESTaurant_backend. Now we're having trouble accessing the database from mysql. The database is already created in the given site itself i.e. "ddl.sql" and we've extracted the tables from there. Under the "Usage" part it says that we can access the database via "localhost/admin" on browser but when I try to access the localhost from browser it just keeps on loading. How do I access the ddl.sql database as shown in the figure in the website. Please help.